# DLL "missing" but present in path

Tags: python, windows, swig

I am in the process of updating our build machine (from Windows Server 2008 to Windows 10), and we need to support both Python 2 and Python 3. We are using SWIG to generate Python bindings for our C++ code. As part of this we generate both a C++ only DLL (mylib_shared.dll, built directly using Clang) and a python-version-specific dll (_mylib.dll, built from swig).

The build is currently fine in Python 2.7, but for Python 3 when I try to import a function from _mylib.dll using the SWIG bindings, I get an error saying the shared dll is missing. This file is identical no matter which version of Python is running, and is definitely present, in the expected place and that directory is in the PATH variable (I've checked, very carefully). I have used `Dependencies` and `dumpbin` to check what it's looking for, the only difference I can see is that Python38.dll (which is obviously imported by the Python 3 version but not the Python 2 version) has a dependency on ws2_32.dll (present in C:\Windows\SysWOW64) that isn't a dependency for the equivalent Python 2 dll. That says it's missing api-ms-win-core-string-obsolete-l1-1-0.dll, but I think this is a red herring - that seems to be an implementation-dependent thing (see https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-files/missing-api-ms-win-core-dlls/d99d1368-0f92-43db-bbdb-7d080f1f96e9). I have checked that everything is being built for the correct architecture (32-bit) by loading the dlls with dumpbin.

So I'm stumped. I had a problem previously with mixed architectures causing a similar problem, but I resolved that and as I say, I'm now checking directly on the dlls being built, so I can't see it's that (also you'd expect it to be a problem for both versions of Python). The file is definitely there. I don't know what else would be causing Windows to claim it can't find the dll. Any help gratefully received!

Comment: Python 3.8+ doesn't search `PATH` or the current directory to resolve DLL dependencies when importing an extension module. It checks the extension module's directory, the application directory (e.g. the directory of "python.exe"), "%SystemRoot%\System32", and user directories added to the DLL search path via [`os.add_dll_directory`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.add_dll_directory).

Comment: This does appear to be the problem (Thank you!), but I couldn't get it to work. Ended up downgrading to Python 3.7, which is behaving.